# Homemade Dressing

Tags: food-safety, salad-dressing

I made a homemade pasta salad dressing. These are the ingredients: 
- Mayo
- Sour Cream
- Fresh Lemon Juice 
- Dried herbs/spices 
I'm just wondering if mixing the lemon juice together with sour cream and mayo will cause it to go bad sooner than the expiration dates call for on the items separately. 
Does anyone have any experience with this? 
Thank you!!

Comment: A bit of an extra basic knowledge, because the linked question has a slightly different angle on the first glance: shelf life is not calculated based on the shelf life of the ingredients. It can be shorter, or longer, or the same as that of any ingredient (or the most perishable ingredient, or whichever you want to choose as a behcnmark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lemon juice contains **citric acid** which actually is used as a preservative in other preparations (like jam, for example). Lemon is also used in some mayo recipes to help stabilize the emulsion. So I believe it **won't accelerate** the spoiling.

However, it can have two undesired effects:

- it can curd the cream, which will still be safe (although yours being sour-cream I believe it won't happen).
- after some days in the fridge it can get very sour and give an unpleasant taste. Happened once with me when making hummus.